# How to get a list of the items in a UWP ComboBox in code behind?

Tags: c++, uwp, c++-winrt

I am not having any luck in figuring out how to get the list of items that are in a ComboBox using code behind. Before I called this code, I appended 3 items to the ComboBox.

```
    vector <IInspectable> items;
    int count = DuringCuttingGasTypeComboBox().Items().GetMany(ZERO, items);
    int size = DuringCuttingGasTypeComboBox().Items().Size();
```

count = zero and the vector is empty, but size = 3 which agrees with the items that the ComboBox currently has.

I suspect that I am not declaring items correctly, but it is compiling and running. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you really want to get, the item data or the ComboBoxItem object?  If you want to get the the `ComboBoxItem` object, DuringCuttingGasTypeComboBox().Items() should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the [`ItemCollection.GetMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemcollection.getmany) explains (in somewhat cryptic terms) how to provide the requested number of items:

> `items`: Provides the destination for the result. **Size the initial array size as a "capacity" in order to specify how many results should be retrieved.**

A default-constructed `vector` has a size of 0, so that's the implied number of items requested by the `GetMany` call. To fix this, the `items` container needs to be properly sized prior to the call, as illustrated here:

```cpp
// Query for the number of items
auto const size = static_cast<size_t>(DuringCuttingGasTypeComboBox().Items().Size());
// Construct a vector of appropriate size
vector <IInspectable> items(size);
// Finally ask for `size` items (implied by the vector's size)
int count = DuringCuttingGasTypeComboBox().Items().GetMany(ZERO, items);
```

That is, if you actually do want to copy (references to) the items into your own collection. It is common to just iterate over the items instead. C++/WinRT makes that very straight forward, in case that's what you need:

```cpp
for (auto const item : DuringCuttingGasTypeComboBox().Items()) {
    // Use `item`
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I knew I was close. The iterator will come in handy. I just might use it the most.